# How can I print from a particular printer in WPF?

Tags: wpf, printing

I have two printers installed, but I want my application to print from the billing printer not from the Deskjet. How can I programmatically achieve that? Setting a default printer is not a good option for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.installedprinters.aspx) would probably a good place to start.

You should then be able to iterate through to find a printer with a PrinterName property that matches the printer you want to print to.